# Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in linux?

Tags: python, linux, debian

I want to write string character to file, but i get error like this `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/python/add.txt'`. how to solve this?

this is my code

```
q = open('/python/add.txt','r')
a = ['123', '234', '456']
lst = []
for line in q:
    for word in a:
        if word in line:
            line = line.replace(word + "\n",'')
    lst.append(line)
q.close()
z = open(r'/python/add.txt','w+')
for line in lst:
    z.write(line)
z.close()
```

Comment: Change the permissions on the file so you can write it.

Comment: Use `ls -l` to inspect permissions and `chmod` to change them.

Comment: this is my file permision using ```ls -l``` ```-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4497050 Apr 26 23:53 add.txt```

Comment: What about permissions on `/python`? You need "w" permissions on directory.

Comment: my directory permision ```drwxrwxrwx   3 root root  4096 Apr 18 07:42 python```

Comment: There is a difference between '/python/add.txt' and 'python/add.txt'

Comment: I guess /python could be mounted read only or with advanced access control. `mount | grep python` and see if "ro" or "acl" is in the option list.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write into a folder called "python" at the root level of the filesystem. This is likely not allowed.

I am guessing you have accidentally put a `/` at the beginning of your file path (making it absolute), when you meant to write `"python/add.txt"`, which is a relative file path.

You should also use the `with` construct when opening files, to ensure they are closed afterwards.

Cleaner version using `with` syntax and better variable names:

```py
add_file_path = 'python/add.txt'
words_to_replace = ['123', '234', '456']
replaced_lines = []
with open(add_file_path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in words_to_replace:
            if word in line:
                line = line.replace(word + "\n",'')
        lst.append(line)

with open(add_file_path, 'w+') as f:
    for line in replaced_lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: if using ```python/addnew.txt``` directory not found

Comment: You need to figure out where you're trying to work. I would strongly suggest not working in a folder at the root level of the filesystem (like '/python'). You should be working in your current working directory and using relative paths.

Comment: here I use a shell script to execute the file, ```/bin/sh /python/filenew.sh``` then in the shell script calls the ```add.text``` file and then loops data from the ```add.text``` and sent to the python file